# Forbidden phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

Whenever I open phpmyadmin I get this error

[image]

my phpmyadmin.conf:

```
 Alias /phpmyadmin "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.9/"

    <Directory "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.9/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1

    # To import big file you can increase values
      php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
      php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
      php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
      php_admin_value max_input_time 360
    </Directory>
```

httpd.conf:

```
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:8083
    Listen 8083


    ServerName localhost:8083
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
    # Virtual Hosts
    #
    <VirtualHost *:8083>
      ServerName localhost
      ServerAlias localhost
      DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www"
      <Directory "E:/wamp/www">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Also I have a problem that the `virtualhost localhost:8083` is not from defined apache variable.

Comment: Why have you moved the port to a non standard number?

Comment: because when i tested the port 80 it says that it is used

Comment: Probably by IIS. If so and you are not using IIS uninstall it

Comment: ***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 1808
The processus of PID 1808 is 'nginx.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 1808 for 'nginx.exe' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampapache64'
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: nginx/1.6.2

Comment: Ok, so you are also using NGINX?

Comment: not really so should i just change back my port to 80 and stop nginx from working

Comment: That would make sense to me

Comment: ***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 seems not actually used.
Unable to initiate a socket connection
Error number: 10061 - Error string: Aucune connexion n�a pu �tre �tablie car l�ordinateur cible l�a express�ment refus�e.

now that i changed the port apach is still not working

Comment: Did you chnage WAMPServer back to using port 80? If so did you start WAMPServer and check that Apache is in fact running

Comment: yes i checked and it still not working in fact there is a new error given in the httpd.conf file " cannot load php into server : Acc\xe8s refus \xe9

Comment: Maybe an uninstall and reinstall will unwind any errors that have been made in the config while you were trying to get it to work